# Geofence in Oreo, Doze Mode

Tags: android, android-geofence

Developing Geofence app for Enter and Exit alerts.
All done using the Google Android Developers Docs : https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#java

Now for Android O, the BroadcastReceiver is registered using the PendingIntent to add the geofence.
While app is running or in background, all geofence alerts were received. But when app is excluded from the recent or phone is in Doze mode, no alerts were received.

I follow almost all forums but not found any solutions.
Looking for the right help for running it on Android O, doze mode.

Comment: I have also tried with Awareness API com.google.android.gms.awareness.fence.AwarenessFence but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that [disabling battery optimizations](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#support_for_other_use_cases), such as Doze mode, improves the responsiveness of geofences on an Android O device. Your mileage may vary on newer versions of Android, as they seem to be constantly tweaking how the OS manages background work such as geofences.